# Heatmap from 3D-data, with float-numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap from 3D-data in a csv-file. The csv-file has the format x,y,z for each line. The problem is when I create a array to link the values, I can't use float-numbers as keys. When setting the dtype to int in np.loadtext(), the code works fine; but this makes the resolution only half of what the csv-file can replicate. Is there another way of linking the values?

The code so far is:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = 'test18.csv'
x, y, z = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=',', dtype=float).T

pltZ = np.zeros((y.max()+1, x.max()+1), dtype=float)
pltZ[y, x] = z

heat_map = sb.heatmap(pltZ, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you include a sample of your data? It could help make reproducing this much easier.

Comment: Thanks! The csv-file in question can be downloaded from this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KiJ5CkxFh9q91HAzteyxfUFLHAM_bz3X/view?usp=sharing